# Connect Raspberry Pi web server to external MySQL database

Tags: php, mysqli, raspberry-pi, apache2

Current situation:
I have a website that requests data from an external (Raspberry Pi) database via php. When I run the website on my computer (Mac OS) everything works perfectly, data is supplied from the external server and then displayed on the website. However, if I run the website on the Raspberry, I cannot access the external server.

No matter what I do, whenever in the php file the line
`mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pw, $database);`
nothing happens afterwards, even if I execute the line in a Try Catch block nothing happens after calling this line. However, if I run the php file on my MacBook, everything works perfectly again. Does anyone have an idea why that is?

Comment: Yes. Mysqli has an exact idea, why it is. All you need is ask. However, adding a Try Catch block *doesn't make* a programming language to throw an exception. It makes no sense to use this operator in order to get the error message. You need to properly configure mysqli instead.

Comment: what did I configure wrong? Everything works perfectly on my MacBook

Comment: There is a link pinned at the top of your question that leads to answer that explains - what exactly you need to configure.